# Acceleration on a rotating frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

##### First Derivation.

Starting from:

$$
\frac{d \mathbf r}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left [ \sum_i r_i \mathbf e_i \right ] = \sum_i\frac{d r_i}{dt} \mathbf e_i + \sum_i r_i\frac{d \mathbf e_i}{dt} = 
$$
$$
= \sum_i\frac{d r_i}{dt} \mathbf e_i + \mathbf \Omega \times \sum_i r_i \mathbf e_i
$$

$$
\left ( \frac{d\mathbf r}{dt} \right )_S = \left ( \frac{d\mathbf r}{dt} \right )_{S'}  + \mathbf \Omega\times \mathbf r
$$
Where $(d\mathbf r / dt)_S$, denotes the rate of change of $\mathbf r$, as measured from the $S$ frame. Same with $(d\mathbf r / dt)_{S'}$ but in the $S'$ frame.
For knowing the second derivative of $\mathbf r$, we have:
$$
\frac{d ^2\mathbf r}{dt ^2} = \ddot{\mathbf r}' + \dot{\mathbf{\Omega}} \times \mathbf r' + 2 \mathbf \Omega \times \dot{\mathbf r}' + \mathbf \Omega \times (\mathbf \Omega \times \mathbf r')
$$
to simplify I've defined $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r'$ as the vector seen in the $S$ frame and $S'$ frame, respectively.
I've took this derivation from the Book "Mechanics - R.Taylor" pg. 339.

##### Second Derivation:

Starting from:
$$
\mathbf r' = \mathcal R \mathbf r
$$
where $\mathcal R$ is a rotation matrix and knowing that:
$$
\hat \Omega = \dot{\mathcal R}^T \mathcal R
$$
$$
\hat \Omega \mathbf r = \mathbf \Omega \times \mathbf r
$$
performing a second order derivation on both sides we arrive to:
$$
\frac{d ^2\mathbf r}{dt ^2} = \mathcal R^T \left ( \ddot{\mathbf r}' + \dot{\mathbf{\Omega'}} \times \mathbf r' + 2 \mathbf \Omega' \times \dot{\mathbf r}' + \mathbf \Omega' \times (\mathbf \Omega' \times \mathbf r') \right )
$$

I found this derivation in our professor notes. This equations are almost identical (excluding the $\mathcal R^T$ factor and the primed $\mathbf \Omega$ on the second one), but shouldn't it be the same? I cannot see the relation (or difference) between assuming that $\mathbf r' = \mathcal R \mathbf r$, or relating both frames of reference via their derivatives? Is there any relation, or a way to go from one equation to another.

Answer (score 0):

from

$$\mathbf r'=\mathbf R\,\mathbf r=\left[\mathbf e_1~,\mathbf e_2~,\mathbf e_2\right]\,\mathbf r=\sum r_i\,\mathbf e_i\quad,\mathbf R^T\,\mathbf R=I_3$$

where the transformation matrix $~\mathbf R~$ transformed the vector coordinates form body fixed system  to inertial system

you obtain he velocity

$$\dot{\mathbf{r}'}=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\,\mathbf r+\mathbf{R}\,\dot{\mathbf{r}}
\quad,\dot{\mathbf{R}}=\mathbf{\hat{\Omega}}\,\mathbf R$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$\dot{\mathbf{r}'}=\mathbf\Omega\times \mathbf R\,\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}\,\dot{\mathbf{r}}$$

multiply this equation from the left with $~\mathbf R^T~$ you obtain your velocity equation